# Using a Decision Tree Algorithm such as C4.5 to understand population Partition

Tags: r, survival, cart, weka, partitioning

I have multivariate data about a certain population with more than 1000 attributes per exemplar.

Some of the variables are basic demographics attributes including: gender, age, race, ethnicity, income level, etc.

What I want to do is come up with an algorithm that proposes "candidate" partition on my sample.

What I mean by candidate is that it would propose say 100 partitions that I would eyeball manually and select say 4 which I found interesting.

A partition is something like:

Sample A

1. 60% are Male
2. 30% out of which are Employed
3. 10% out of which own cars

Sample B

1. 60% are Male
2. 40% out of which are College educated
3. 20% out of which are married.

I was thinking of using a decision tree like algorithm that works off of information gain to do the above.

Question:

1. Is the above feasible?
2. Should I write my custom code or do you know of code in Java, Python that does the above?
3. Any other pointers?

Notes:

1. What is interesting -- really what might deliver insight to a business user. What I'm trying to do is try to present partitions that are about 4 levels deep that might be interesting to a user. So for example the goal is to come up with a lot off em but one a human expert could sift through in a day.
2. Now I understand my note on "interesting" may draw ridicule -- I understand it is a very weak statement -- an alternative I was thinking off is to create an interactive system where an expert could perform step by step breakdowns have taking into account suggestions from the results of a modified C4.5 algorithm

Comment: C45 can be tuned to build such kind of groups.  However, before delving into details: what problem do you want to solve?  What means interesting?

Comment: @unreasonablelearner, hi, I'll try edit the question some more.